# Are there any general purpose exception-handling frameworks for capturing and managing exceptions?

Tags: exception, jira, marklogic

We have a system built on MarkLogic, Java / GlassFish.  We need some kind of system that could capture thrown exceptions from any of those three subsystems, and then provide a nice web-based reporting interface where exceptions could be viewed, prioritized, marked done.  We use JIRA.com in the cloud so if there was any way to integrate with that, it would be nice.  Prefer open source or inexpensive.

I'm not sure whether a Java-based system would accomodate our MarkLogic errors, so I believe we need something that is language-agnostic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are communicating with MarkLogic using a MarkLogic "HTTP appserver" (as opposed to XCC or WebDAV), then you can use the error handler configuration as a choke point for catching unhandled exceptions.  I've never tried this, but, in theory, in the error handler, you could make an http request and send them anywhere you want.

See http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/xml/dev_guide/appserver-control.xml%2387072

If you are using XCC, then there are other places to put choke points in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic writes exceptions by default to the Data/Logs/ErrorLog.txt file. Application code within MarkLogic can use xdmp:log, or trace() to log messages to the same file. The file can be accessed quite easily through file-system if GlassFish is running on the same host.,  It can also be disclosed through an App Server within MarkLogic with some custom XQuery code.

GlassFish itself appears to be a Java EE platform. I expect it to do logging using something like Log4J. The logging messages in the ErrorLog and the Log4J log will likely not be formatted identically, but basic properties should be there, like date/time, and error message. Log4J logging can be set to write to a log file as well. You could consume it in a similar way as the ErrorLog.

I am not aware of any error reporting web-interface for such logging, but I believe JIRA provides an HTTP API, which can be used to push information into it.